# Delimited columns in linux with awk

Tags: awk

I have a file (df.txt) with 2 fields, but the first field has different size:

```
HOL99001 121112120001121122020112122010202121010100022002021................
804B 121202011100121121200010200120202220111200011002010....................
WW9 212202021000022111111111201001110001111200020200211.....................
```

I use a program that requires that the second field must start at the same position in different lines, thus:

```
HOL99001    121112120001121122020112122010202121010100022002021
804B        121202011100121121200010200120202220111200011002010
WW9         212202021000022111111111201001110001111200020200211
```

I am using

```
awk '{print $1.8, $2}' df.txt > dfinal.txt
```

Comment: Please provide sample input and expected output and what is `$1.8`  supposed to be doing?

Comment: I second anubhava sir here. Good that you have shown your efforts in form of code keep it up. But samples of input and expected output equally  important same as efforts, your samples aren't clear so kindly edit your question and let us know then.

Comment: @anubhava  1.8 means that the size for field 1 is max 8

Comment: `awk '{printf "%-8s%s%s%s", $1, OFS, $2, ORS}' file` should work.

Comment: Are the trailing dots part of the file or are they placeholders for spaces?

Comment: @Cyrus placeholders for other numbers, the size is 800k

Comment: If the `column` command is available on your platform, you can simply use `column -t df.txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
gawk '{printf("%8s %s\n", $1, $2)}' df.txt
HOL99001 121112120001121122020112122010202121010100022002021
    804B 121202011100121121200010200120202220111200011002010
     WW9 212202021000022111111111201001110001111200020200211
```

or:

```
gawk '{printf("%-8s %s\n", $1, $2)}' df.txt
HOL99001 121112120001121122020112122010202121010100022002021
804B     121202011100121121200010200120202220111200011002010
WW9      212202021000022111111111201001110001111200020200211
```

Comment: @JohannaRamirez GNU awk is gawk, not gwak, but the above code should work with any awk.

Comment: @James Brown sorry,  it was a typo, I do not know why it does not work